# AIX 7.1 gmake shell clearing $NLSPATH?

Tags: gnu-make, aix

I'm not following how the environment variable $NLSPATH value is being cleared/reset when running gmake. In my bash shell, if I issue echo $NLSPATH, I see the expected /usr/lib/nls/msg/%L/%N: (etc).

I then create a Makefile like this:

```
all:
    echo $$NLSPATH
    echo $$PATH
```

And running gmake all gives me

```
echo $NLSPATH

echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/etc:(etc as expected)
```

I also tried -e with the same result;

```
gmake -e all
echo $NLSPATH

echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/etc:(etc as expected)
```

I've looked at /etc/environment and /etc/.profile and $NLSPATH is set correctly there.

Also if I run the standard AIX make, the NLSPATH is shown as expected. So this seems to be gmake and/or the way it invokes the current shell.

Could someone suggest where I should be looking ? [EDIT]
As I'm new, I can't hit answer right away... 
Finally found it - The following technote describes it (albeit briefly) as a security limitation;

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21516415

Issuing;

```
cd /opt/freeware/bin 
sudo chmod -s make
```

solves this issue for me although I'm left wondering there is some aspect of gmake that may later expect the setuid flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC GNU make on AIX needs the setgid flag in order to enable the `-l` flag, because on this OS you can't retrieve the load average of the system as a normal user (no idea why that is considered *more* of a security issue than having any program that needs to check the load average be setgid, but... no one asked me).

As long as you don't use `-l` when running GNU make, you won't have any problem.